# Set up a Calendar Trigger immediately after creating the calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, runtime, google-calendar-api, eventtrigger

So I'm trying to set up an onEventUpdated trigger on a recently created calendar. The function creates a Sheet, a Calendar and a Trigger for that calendar, but the trigger can't be created due to the recent creation of the calendar and I get an error "Exception: No tienes acceso al calendario" (I'm sorry my native language is Spanish, but this can be translated as "Exception: You don't have access to the calendar").

I tried to solve this with a Utilities.sleep, but it has to wait like 15 secs to function properly, I think that's too much time. U have any other solution for this? I'll paste my code

```
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function addPerson() {
  const personPrompt = ui.prompt('TITLE','Por favor ingrese el nombre de la persona a añadir.', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  const personName = personPrompt.getResponseText();
  const calendar = CalendarApp.createCalendar(personName);
  const calendarID = calendar.getId();
  const sheet = SS.insertSheet(personName, SS.getSheets().length);
  Utilities.sleep(15000); //Here is the workaround that I found
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('masterFunction')
    .forUserCalendar(calendarID)
    .onEventUpdated()
    .create();
}
```

I removed some of the lines that doesn't have anything to do with the problem, I hope u can help. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Create this:

```
function myfunk() {
  Logger.log("I am here.");//Just something to catch the trigger
}
```

Run First:

```
function createACalendar() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const calendar = CalendarApp.createCalendar("Calendar1");
  const calendarID = calendar.getId();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("calid",calendarID);
}
```

Run Next:

```
function createTheTrigger() {
  let calendarID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("calid");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myfunk')
    .forUserCalendar(calendarID)
    .onEventUpdated()
    .create();
}
```

Then this:

```
function myfunction() {
  let calendarID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("calid");
  let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
  let st = new Date();
  let ed = new Date();
  ed.setHours(23);//this may not work for you
  cal.createEvent("Event1",st,ed);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, I still get: 
`
Exception: You do not have access to the calendar.
createTheTrigger @ test.gs:19
createACalendar @ test.gs:11
`
I copy pasted your solution and added the other functions. I need to run the functions immediately after the other so at the end of createACalendar function I added createTheTrigger(), and I still get this error

Comment: It takes a while to create the calendar so that fact that you think you need to do it immediately after creation doesn't really matter.  You will have to wait until the calendar is created.  I tested the code and it worked for me.

Comment: Jummmm, so I guess I'll stick to the Utilities.sleep(15000) for the wait part. Thx for ur response anyway, it was very helpfull.